# FragmentActivity incompatible with FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I'm making a an app with that displays data with swipe views. I have used fragmentactivity in all class but it causes error in the tabpagedapater which is that it is incompatible with fragmentstatepageadapter how do i fix this?

Tabpageadapter.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public FragmentActivity getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            //Fragement for Android Tab
            return new Android();
        case 1:
           //Fragment for Ios Tab
            return new Ios();
        case 2:
            //Fragment for Windows Tab
            return new Windows();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }




    }
```

Mainactivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.learn2crack.library.DatabaseHandler;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Android extends FragmentActivity {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {


            View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android_frag, container, false);
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

            HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
            user = db.getUserDetails();

            /**
             * Displays the registration details in Text view
             **/

            final TextView fname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fname);
            final TextView lname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lname);
            final TextView uname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uname);
            final TextView email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
            final TextView created_at = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.regat);
            fname.setText(user.get("fname"));
            lname.setText(user.get("lname"));
            uname.setText(user.get("uname"));
            email.setText(user.get("email"));
            created_at.setText(user.get("created_at"));

            return android;
}}
```

Comment: In all your fragments change "extends FragmentActivity" to "extends Fragment"

Comment: how can I use the findviewbyid and getapplicationcontext by extending the class with a fragment?

Comment: for that u can do like this "getActivity().getApplicationContext()" and to use "findViewById" u must do like this : yourView.findViewById() here yourView is that view that you inflate in your fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this.

```
 @Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}
```

Also in your `Android`  class extends with `Fragment` instead of `FragmentActivity`

Note: Check that if you have extended same  with `FragmentActivity` instead of `Fragment` for `Ios` and `Windows` class. If it is then change like above i said.

UPDATE:

You are using `Fragment` so as a `Context` you need to use `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

So change here

```
  DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
```

Also here

```
  final TextView fname = (TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.fname);
  final TextView lname = (TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.lname);
  final TextView uname = (TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.uname);
  final TextView email = (TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.email);
  final TextView created_at = (TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.regat);
```

Because when you'r using Fragments you need to pass View's object for find id for UI elements as a refernce.

Comment: extending it with fragment causes the findviewbyid and getapplicationcontext() generate errors how do i work with both fragment and activity?